# Set ALL pixels to black if values at position is 0

Tags: python, numpy

I have images with the same shape defined as:

```
 img = cv2.imread(file, 0)  # values are 0 - 255 
 mask = cv2.imread(file2, 0) # values are only 0's and 255's
```

From the given images, I want to check if at mask[x,y] = 0, then set the img[x,y] = 0.

I can do this by doing a loop.  But is there a way that I can do this in a numPyish way?

Comment: Maybe `np.where()` can help you

Comment: I am still new to numPy really.  So I still have no idea on how to do things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a mask (not the same as your existing variable) and apply it to the `img` array to specifically target indexes where you want to put a 0. Then it's as simple as:

```
mask2 = (mask == 0)
img[mask2] = 0
```

Alternatively,

```
img[mask.astype(bool)] = 0
```